# Rubymine 6.3.2 doesn't find environment variables on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables, rubymine, ubuntu-13.10

I'm trying to execute a `bundle install` via RubyMine but I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Error Message:
    Set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME if Oracle Full Client.
    Append the path of Oracle client libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if Oracle Instant Client.
```

I'm using Oracle Instant Client and my `~/.bash_profile` contains this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

I have no issues when I try `bundle install` via terminal. I suspect that Rubymine is not loading the same environment variables that the terminal app loads when it starts.

Answer (score 2):

run RubyMine, go to Tools -> Create Command-Line Launcher, it should create a `/usr/local/bin/mine` file.

Edit your RubyMine launcher in Ubuntu, and make it execute `bash -ic '/usr/local/bin/mine'` (the `-i` is for an interactive shell)

That will launch RubyMine after loading your profile files (.profile, .bashrc ...)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running RubyMine from your desktop manager and none of the parents of the desktop manager run your `~/.bash_profile`. Fixing that would be an Ubuntu question.

But you could

- find the RubyMine executable on disk and run RubyMine by typing the full path of the executable in a terminal (and you could make an alias), or
- run RubyMine, go to Tools -> Create Command-Line Launcher, and use the launcher that it creates.